# How do I do a running total with a conditional reset from two columns, by person?

Tags: r, database, dplyr

There is a guest log of residents at an RV park. By city law, residents can stay for no more than 150 days without a 14 day hiatus from the park. If a resident leaves for <10 days, and checks back in, those days are added to their running total.

So I am looking for a way to total up each resident's time at the park, while restarting that running total when a hiatus of longer than 10 days is taken.

We are given a table with each person's arrival and departure dates.

```
today <- Sys.Date(01/01/2019,"%m/%d/%Y")
hiatus <- ifelse(name == lag(name), arrival-lag(depart), 0)
stay <- ifelse(is.na(depart), as.numeric(today-arrival), depart-arrival)

resident     arrival     departure    hiatus    stay   sincehiatus
Snow, Jon    17633       17652        0         19     19          
Snow, Jon    17656       17683        4         27     50        
Snow, Jon    17683       17713        0         30     80
Snow, Jon    17713       17752        0         39     119
Snow, Jon    17763       17775        11        12     12
Snow, Jon    17775       17805        0         30     42
Snow, Jon    17805       17836        0         31     73
Snow, Jon    17836       17882        0         46     119
Snow, Jon    17895       N/A          13        2      2
Stark, Bran  17823       17831        0         8      10
Stark, Bran  17831       17845        0         14     24
Stark, Bran  17845       17847        0         2      26
Stark, Bran  17847       17849        0         2      28
Stark, Bran  17859       N/A          10        38     38
```

I've gone ahead and created a "*hiatus*" variable and a "*stay*" variable, defined below.

For an *N/A* in departure, that means the resident is still on-site. Thus today's date is used as their departure date when calculating *stay*.

What I need to create is a variable that shows the number of days since last 10 day hiatus (*sincehiatus*).

I've manually input what "*sincehiatus*" ought to look like, I'm just having trouble getting there.

For each person, *sincehiatus* = *hiatus* + *stay* + lag(*sincehiatus*), and when *hiatus* > 10, *sincehiatus* = *stay*

I'm wondering how do a running total per individual. I'm having trouble connecting the dots with other postings I've seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is to find streaks of "contiguous" stays, i.e., where any hiatus was less than 10 days. This is accomplished by creating a `stay.id` for each `resident` by `cumsum(hiatus >= 10)` and grouping accordingly.

#### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
today <- as.Date("01/01/2019","%m/%d/%Y")
ds %>% 
  arrange(resident, arrival) %>% # just to ensure proper row order
  group_by(resident) %>% 
  mutate(stay.id = cumsum(arrival - lag(departure, default = 0) >= 10)) %>% 
  group_by(resident, stay.id) %>% 
  mutate(sh = ifelse(is.na(departure), today, departure) - min(arrival))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 14 x 8
> # Groups:   resident, stay.id [5]
>    resident    arrival departure hiatus  stay sincehiatus stay.id    sh
>    <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>   <int> <dbl>
>  1 Snow, Jon     17633     17652      0    19          19       1    19
>  2 Snow, Jon     17656     17683      4    27          50       1    50
>  3 Snow, Jon     17683     17713      0    30          80       1    80
>  4 Snow, Jon     17713     17752      0    39         119       1   119
>  5 Snow, Jon     17763     17775     11    12          12       2    12
>  6 Snow, Jon     17775     17805      0    30          42       2    42
>  7 Snow, Jon     17805     17836      0    31          73       2    73
>  8 Snow, Jon     17836     17882      0    46         119       2   119
>  9 Snow, Jon     17895        NA     13     2           2       3     2
> 10 Stark, Bran   17823     17831      0     8          10       1     8
> 11 Stark, Bran   17831     17845      0    14          24       1    22
> 12 Stark, Bran   17845     17847      0     2          26       1    24
> 13 Stark, Bran   17847     17849      0     2          28       1    26
> 14 Stark, Bran   17859        NA     10    38          38       2    38
> ```

The new column `sh` is in line with OP's expctations (except for rows 10 to 13 where the OP seems to have added the 2 days from Jon Snow's last visit to Bran Stark's first).

#### `data.table`

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` version which creates the grouping variable on-the-fly and which updates `ds` *by reference*, i.e., the new column is appended without copying the whole data object.

```
library(data.table)
today <- as.Date("01/01/2019","%m/%d/%Y")
setDT(ds)[order(arrival), sh := ifelse(is.na(departure), today, departure) - min(arrival), 
          by = .(resident, cumsum(arrival - shift(departure, fill = 0) >= 10))][]
ds
```

> ```
>        resident arrival departure hiatus stay sincehiatus  sh
>  1:   Snow, Jon   17633     17652      0   19          19  19
>  2:   Snow, Jon   17656     17683      4   27          50  50
>  3:   Snow, Jon   17683     17713      0   30          80  80
>  4:   Snow, Jon   17713     17752      0   39         119 119
>  5:   Snow, Jon   17763     17775     11   12          12  12
>  6:   Snow, Jon   17775     17805      0   30          42  42
>  7:   Snow, Jon   17805     17836      0   31          73  73
>  8:   Snow, Jon   17836     17882      0   46         119 119
>  9:   Snow, Jon   17895        NA     13    2           2   2
> 10: Stark, Bran   17823     17831      0    8          10   8
> 11: Stark, Bran   17831     17845      0   14          24  22
> 12: Stark, Bran   17845     17847      0    2          26  24
> 13: Stark, Bran   17847     17849      0    2          28  26
> 14: Stark, Bran   17859        NA     10   38          38  38
> ```

#### Data

```
ds <- readr::read_table("
resident     arrival     departure    hiatus    stay   sincehiatus
Snow, Jon    17633       17652        0         19     19          
Snow, Jon    17656       17683        4         27     50        
Snow, Jon    17683       17713        0         30     80
Snow, Jon    17713       17752        0         39     119
Snow, Jon    17763       17775        11        12     12
Snow, Jon    17775       17805        0         30     42
Snow, Jon    17805       17836        0         31     73
Snow, Jon    17836       17882        0         46     119
Snow, Jon    17895       N/A          13        2      2
Stark, Bran  17823       17831        0         8      10
Stark, Bran  17831       17845        0         14     24
Stark, Bran  17845       17847        0         2      26
Stark, Bran  17847       17849        0         2      28
Stark, Bran  17859       N/A          10        38     38"
                  , na = "N/A")
```